# Trouble binding native Obj-C library to Xamarin.iOS Project

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios, objective-sharpie, fat-binaries

I am running into difficulty trying to bind a native Obj-C static library I created in XCode to my Xamarin.iOS project. I went through the necessary steps creating a Fat Binary. It created both x86 and ARM architectures but it throws an error saying it cannot find the native Obj-C class inside the wrapper class. When i checked the arm symbol table using the following command "nm -arch  ", the symbol table was empty

Link to the Example I tried following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-objective-c/walkthrough?tabs=windows#Creating_A_Static_Library

Comment: Could you please provide more error logs so that we can help you to solve this problem?

Comment: What I meant by errors is when I copied over the api definition generated from sharpie I get thousands of errors saying class names do not exist in the current context. Sorry I am not clear about the issue. It's my first time trying to bind a native Obj-C Library in Xamarin. Is there possibly another way I can do this without having to bind a native library? Sorry if my reply wasn't much help, I thought mentioning what the goal is could maybe send us down a better route for finding a better solution.

Comment: My overall goal is to implement the code found in the link below under the section "File Integrity Checks (Sample Implementation - Application Source Code)". My problem is when writing the code in my Xamarin.iOS project I need access to the following libraries #include <dlfcn.h> and #include <mach-o/dyld.h>.

https://sushi2k.gitbooks.io/the-owasp-mobile-security-testing-guide/content/0x06j-Testing-Resiliency-Against-Reverse-Engineering.html